# Ancho y alto imagen de relleno de path svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

estoy desarrollando un mapa interactivo en el cual aparecerán los países del continente americano, cada país debe de tener una imagen e fondo con algo representativo con dicho país, esto lo estoy haciendo con la librería JVectorMap, ya he logrado insertar la silueta de un país y una imagen de fondo para dicho país, el problema viene al momento de ajustar la imagen al tamaño el país, quiero hacer que la imagen se adapte a la anchura del país y la altura se automática, ya lo he intentado modificando los valores width y height de a etiqueta pattern y image de la imagen pero no funciona, he dado tamaños en porcentajes, valores máximos, pero no logro hacer que se adapte.
espero me puedan ayudar.

```html
<html><head
</head>
<body>
  <div id="world-map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"><div class="jvectormap-container" style="background-color: rgb(80, 80, 80);"><svg width="500" height="500">
    <defs>
      <pattern id="image2" x="0" y="0" width="525" height="350" viewBox="0 0 1050 700" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><image xlink:href="https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/02/04/universal/5cdmxES2/5cdmxES2-master1050.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1050" height="700"></image></pattern>
    </defs>
    <g transform="scale(1.2155555555555555) translate(0, 89.79309691312544)"><path d="M133.12,200.41l0.2,0.47l9.63,3.33l6.96,-0.02l0.4,-0.4l0.0,-0.74l3.77,0.0l3.55,2.93l1.39,2.83l1.52,1.04l2.08,0.82l0.47,-0.14l1.46,-2.0l1.73,-0.04l1.59,0.98l2.05,3.35l1.47,1.56l1.26,3.14l2.18,1.02l2.26,0.58l-1.18,3.72l-0.42,5.04l1.79,4.89l1.62,1.89l0.61,1.52l1.2,1.42l2.55,0.66l1.37,1.1l7.54,-1.89l1.86,-1.3l1.14,-4.3l4.1,-1.21l3.57,-0.11l0.32,0.3l-0.06,0.94l-1.26,1.45l-0.67,1.71l0.38,0.7l-0.72,2.27l-0.49,-0.3l-1.0,0.08l-1.0,1.39l-0.47,-0.11l-0.53,0.47l-4.26,-0.02l-0.4,0.4l-0.0,1.06l-1.1,0.26l0.1,0.44l1.82,1.44l0.56,0.91l-3.19,0.21l-1.21,2.09l0.24,0.72l-0.2,0.44l-2.24,-2.18l-1.45,-0.93l-2.22,-0.69l-1.52,0.22l-3.07,1.16l-10.55,-3.85l-2.86,-1.96l-3.78,-0.92l-1.08,-1.19l-2.62,-1.43l-1.18,-1.54l-0.38,-0.81l0.66,-0.63l-0.18,-0.53l0.52,-0.76l0.01,-0.91l-2.0,-3.82l-2.21,-2.63l-2.53,-2.09l-1.19,-1.62l-2.2,-1.17l-0.3,-0.43l0.34,-1.48l-0.21,-0.45l-1.23,-0.6l-1.36,-1.2l-0.59,-1.78l-1.54,-0.47l-2.44,-2.55l-0.16,-0.9l-1.33,-2.03l-0.84,-1.99l-0.16,-1.33l-1.81,-1.1l-0.97,0.05l-1.31,-0.7l-0.57,0.22l-0.4,1.12l0.72,3.77l3.51,3.89l0.28,0.78l0.53,0.26l0.41,1.43l1.33,1.73l1.58,1.41l0.8,2.39l1.43,2.41l0.13,1.32l0.37,0.36l1.04,0.08l1.67,2.28l-0.85,0.76l-0.66,-1.51l-1.68,-1.54l-2.91,-1.87l0.06,-1.82l-0.54,-1.68l-2.91,-2.03l-0.55,0.09l-1.95,-1.1l-0.88,-0.94l0.68,-0.08l0.93,-1.01l0.08,-1.78l-1.93,-1.94l-1.46,-0.77l-3.75,-7.56l4.88,-0.42Z" data-code="MX" fill="url(#image2)" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" class="jvectormap-region jvectormap-element"></path></g><g></g><g></g><g></g></svg><div class="jvectormap-zoomin">+</div><div class="jvectormap-zoomout">−</div><div class="jvectormap-legend-cnt jvectormap-legend-cnt-h"></div><div class="jvectormap-legend-cnt jvectormap-legend-cnt-v"></div></div></div>
<div class="jvectormap-tip"></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observación: Siempre que trabajas con svg utiliza el atributo viewBox.

En lugar de utilizar un patron prefiero cortar la imagen con clipPath. Para establecer el tamaño y la posición de la imagen necesitas saber el tamaño de la caja delimitadora (bounding box) del trazado (en este caso `<path id="mx"`). Para esto utilizo el método `getBBox()` También necesito saber el tamaño de la imagen, en este caso `let iw = 915,ih = 610;`

Ulteriormente viene una función que recalcula y establece el tamaño de la imagen en función de la proporción entre la altura y la anchura de la imagen y del trazado.

Espero que sea útil.

```js
let bb = mx.getBBox(),//la caja delimitadora del trazado #mx
sw = bb.width,//la anchura del elemento svg (#mx)
sh = bb.height;//la altura del elemento svg (#mx)
let iw = 915,ih = 610;//la anchura y la altura original de la imágen

//una función que recalcula el tamaño de la imágen
function svgCover(sw,sh,iw,ih) {
  // relación alto / ancho para el elemento svg
  let s_ratio = sw / sh;
  // relación alto / ancho para la imagen
  let i_ratio = iw / ih;
  // si la proporción altura/anchura de la imagen y del elemento svg es la misma
  if (s_ratio == i_ratio) {
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"width",sw);
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"height",sh);
  }
  //si la proporción altura/anchura del elemento svg es > la proporción altura/anchura de la imagen
  if (s_ratio > i_ratio) {
    let ratio = sw / iw;
    IW = sw;
    IH = ih * ratio;
    let offsetY = -(IH - sh) / 2; 
    // para centrar la imagen
    // establece el valor del attributo y width y height de la imagen
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"y",bb.y + offsetY);
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"width",IW);
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"height",IH);
  }
  //si la proporción altura/anchura del elemento svg es < la proporción altura/anchura de la imagen
  if (s_ratio < i_ratio) {
    let ratio = sh / ih;
    IH = sh;
    IW = iw * ratio;
    let offsetX = -(IW - sw) / 2; 
    // para centrar la imagen
    // establece el valor del attributo y width y height de la imagen
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"x",bb.x + offsetX);
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"width",IW);
    laImagen.setAttributeNS(null,"height",IH);
  }
}


svgCover(sw,sh,iw,ih)
```

```css
svg{background:#555}
```

```html
 <svg width="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" > 
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="Mexico"><path  id="mx" d="M133.12,200.41l0.2,0.47l9.63,3.33l6.96,-0.02l0.4,-0.4l0.0,-0.74l3.77,0.0l3.55,2.93l1.39,2.83l1.52,1.04l2.08,0.82l0.47,-0.14l1.46,-2.0l1.73,-0.04l1.59,0.98l2.05,3.35l1.47,1.56l1.26,3.14l2.18,1.02l2.26,0.58l-1.18,3.72l-0.42,5.04l1.79,4.89l1.62,1.89l0.61,1.52l1.2,1.42l2.55,0.66l1.37,1.1l7.54,-1.89l1.86,-1.3l1.14,-4.3l4.1,-1.21l3.57,-0.11l0.32,0.3l-0.06,0.94l-1.26,1.45l-0.67,1.71l0.38,0.7l-0.72,2.27l-0.49,-0.3l-1.0,0.08l-1.0,1.39l-0.47,-0.11l-0.53,0.47l-4.26,-0.02l-0.4,0.4l-0.0,1.06l-1.1,0.26l0.1,0.44l1.82,1.44l0.56,0.91l-3.19,0.21l-1.21,2.09l0.24,0.72l-0.2,0.44l-2.24,-2.18l-1.45,-0.93l-2.22,-0.69l-1.52,0.22l-3.07,1.16l-10.55,-3.85l-2.86,-1.96l-3.78,-0.92l-1.08,-1.19l-2.62,-1.43l-1.18,-1.54l-0.38,-0.81l0.66,-0.63l-0.18,-0.53l0.52,-0.76l0.01,-0.91l-2.0,-3.82l-2.21,-2.63l-2.53,-2.09l-1.19,-1.62l-2.2,-1.17l-0.3,-0.43l0.34,-1.48l-0.21,-0.45l-1.23,-0.6l-1.36,-1.2l-0.59,-1.78l-1.54,-0.47l-2.44,-2.55l-0.16,-0.9l-1.33,-2.03l-0.84,-1.99l-0.16,-1.33l-1.81,-1.1l-0.97,0.05l-1.31,-0.7l-0.57,0.22l-0.4,1.12l0.72,3.77l3.51,3.89l0.28,0.78l0.53,0.26l0.41,1.43l1.33,1.73l1.58,1.41l0.8,2.39l1.43,2.41l0.13,1.32l0.37,0.36l1.04,0.08l1.67,2.28l-0.85,0.76l-0.66,-1.51l-1.68,-1.54l-2.91,-1.87l0.06,-1.82l-0.54,-1.68l-2.91,-2.03l-0.55,0.09l-1.95,-1.1l-0.88,-0.94l0.68,-0.08l0.93,-1.01l0.08,-1.78l-1.93,-1.94l-1.46,-0.77l-3.75,-7.56l4.88,-0.42Z" ></path></clipPath></defs>

<g id="KK">
<image transform="scale(1.2155555555555555) translate(0, 89.79309691312544)" id="laImagen" x="128" y="200" xlink:href = "https://static01.nyt.com/images/2017/02/04/universal/5cdmxES2/5cdmxES2-master1050.jpg"  clip-path="url(#Mexico)" />
   </g>

</svg>
```